# How to get width of equation

Tags: align, lengths

If I want to know the width of a text I use

```
\settowidth{\MyLength}{bla}.
```

Is there something similar for equations?

More specifically I have

```
\begin{align}
a & b & c & d\\
c & d & c & d
\end{align}
```

and I would like to have the width of this `align` section.
How can I get this?

Comment: Does this include the equation number associated with using `align`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Use `\settowidth{\MyLength}{$<equation>$}`, bacailly use math mode for the equation you want to measure.  Of course it can not contain align points `&`.

Comment: An `align` is as wide as the text, so the answer is `\textwidth`.  Do you mean the width of the math itself from leftmost to rightmost symbol?  This is dependent on the text width, since the `align` environment will add space between the columns to space them evenly.  If you want a "generic" aligned width, you could try using the `aligned` environment inside Peter Grill's suggestion, i.e. `\settowidth{\MyLength}{$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$}`.  This environment "shrinks to fit".

Answer (score 6):

One can get the sum of the widths of the "equation" parts, as the spacing between alignment groups is computed dynamically and is stored nowhere.

The column widths are stored in a special format in the macro `\maxcolumn@widths`, which is available at the end of the construction, when the conditional `\ifmeasuring@` is false. The format is

```
\or <dimen1> \or <dimen2> \or ...
```

where each `<dimen>` is the maximum width of the respective column (`align` builds `rlrl...` alignments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}
\makeatother

\newlength{\mylen}


\begin{document}
\settowidthofalign{\mylen}{
a & b & c & d\\
c & d & c & d
}

\the\mylen

\end{document}
```

One *may* add to this the computation of the horizontal space really used from the left to the right.

Comment: What would the code for `\settowidthofalign` become in LaTeX3 syntax?