# Measuring maximum height of row within align

Tags: align, lengths

Is there a way to extract the maximum height of a row within an align environment? For example, given

```
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{1}{2}\\
b &= 0.25
\end{align}
```

I would like to extract the height the individual rows, in particular, the height of the largest row. It is possible to [extract the width of the individual columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59925/how-to-get-width-of-equation?rq=1) but I couldn't find a way to do the same for the row heights.