# Missing } inserted after redefining equation and align environments

Tags: equations, align, environments, expl3, latex3

In the following mwe I'm redefining the `equation` and `align` environments to save the width of their contents via a `\settowidthofalign` macro copied from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59955/172923) post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59955/172923
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_eqn_width_dim

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldequation }{ equation }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldequation }{ endequation }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ equation }{ +b }
  {
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \use:c { oldequation }
      #1
    \use:c { endoldequation }
  }{}

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldalign }{ align }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldalign }{ endalign }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ align }{ +b }
  {
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \use:c { oldalign }
      #1
    \use:c { endoldalign }
  }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the error

```
./realign.tex:49: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.49 \end
         {equation}
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `align*`, which you use to measure, is defined with

```latex
\newenvironment{align*}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
```

but you redefined `\endalign` to do nothing in your new environment, so you only have half the code for `align*` there.  You need to redefine `\endalign*` to expand to `\endoldalign`:

```
\cs_set:cpn { endalign* }{ \endoldalign }
```

Second: you use:

```latex
    \use:c { oldalign }
    #1
    \use:c { endoldalign }
```

but `oldalign` (which is `align` here) looks for the tokens `\end{oldalign}` literally to determine the end of the environment, and it won't find it hidden in `\use:c`: you need to use the environment form here:

```latex
    \begin{oldalign}
      #1
    \end{oldalign}
```

Change those and it seems to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59955/172923
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_eqn_width_dim

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldequation }{ equation }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldequation }{ endequation }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ equation }{ +b }
  {
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \use:c { oldequation }
      #1
    \use:c { endoldequation }
  }{}

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldalign }{ align }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldalign }{ endalign }
\cs_set:cpn { endalign* }{ \endoldalign }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ align }{ +b }
  {
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \begin{oldalign}
      #1
    \end{oldalign}
  }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I renew the `equation*` environment in that way, `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` works, but `\[ ... \]` gives the error `LaTeX error: \begin{align*} on input line x ended by \end{equation*}`. What should I change?

Comment: @noibe That happens because `amsmath` redefines `\[` and `\]` to be `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`, so when you do `\[ math \]` you essentially have `\begin{equation*} math \]`, and when `xparse` tries to look for the `\end{equation*}` it fails.  You can work around that by making `\[` look for the matching `\]` and grab everything in between: `\RenewDocumentCommand \[ { u \] } { \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 } \use:c { oldequation* } #1 \use:c { endoldequation* } } { }`.  It won't behave _exactly_ like the original definition though (like if you have `\string\]`).

Comment: "It won't behave exactly like the original definition though (like if you have `\string\]`)" what do you mean?

Comment: @noibe A “normal” environment (that doesn't grab its contents) doesn't care what the `\end` part looks like as long as its there.  You can do `\def\boo{\end{equation}}` then proceed with `\begin{equation}{c} \boo` and it will work.  It will also work if you do, say, `\begin{equation}{c} \verb|\end{equation}| \boo`: roughly, it cares what the commands _mean_, not what they _look like_.  An environment that grabs its contents is the other way around; it cares what the `\end` _looks like_. If you replace the `equation` environment in the examples above by `align` you'll get an error (cont)

Comment: ...because the `\end{align}` inside the `\verb` is used as delimiter (it doesn't care about what `\verb` means).  My remark about `\[ ... \]` is that it usually is a normal environment, but if you redefine it like that it can be tricked with things like `\[ \verb=\]= \]` or `\[ \string\] \]`, that would have worked otherwise.  Basically it means that you cannot have `\]` (or `\end{align}` or whatever end delimiter) inside the environment, _other than_ the actual end delimiter.  For `align` it is usually okay, but `\]` is much more likely to show up out of context.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the brief lesson, I'll keep that in mind.