# LaTeX complains about overfull \hbox but no box is actually overfull

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, warnings

In the following mwe I'm redefining the `equation*` environment to store the width of its contents in a token list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59955/172923
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_eqn_width_dim

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldequation* }{ equation* }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldequation* }{ endequation* }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ equation* }{ +b }
  {
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \begin{oldequation*} #1 \end{oldequation*}
  }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  (b_{n + 1}, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - \sum_{j = 1}^{n} (v_{n + 1}, e_j) \,
  (e_j, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - (v_{n + 1}, e_m)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

however, when I run the code I get the warning

```
Overfull \hbox (1.07913pt too wide) detected at line 37
```

even though the content of `equation*` is clearly within the page margins:

[image]

I suspect the warning is not generated by `equation*` itself, but by `align*`, which is used in the `\settowidthofalign` macro. Indeed, commenting out

```
% \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
```

gets rid of the warning. How can I fix this?

Comment: `align` seems to take a bit more horizontal space than `equation`. Try just setting the equation in an `align*` environment with `\overfullrule=5pt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't see the overfull box as you are typesetting `equation*` but internally using `align*` the flush left implementation loses some shrinkability, if you remove the redefinitions and just set both forms then you see the same overfull box also output

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  (b_{n + 1}, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - \sum_{j = 1}^{n} (v_{n + 1}, e_j) \,
  (e_j, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - (v_{n + 1}, e_m)
\end{equation*}


align
\begin{align*}
  (b_{n + 1}, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - \sum_{j = 1}^{n} (v_{n + 1}, e_j) \,
  (e_j, e_m) = (v_{n + 1}, e_m) - (v_{n + 1}, e_m)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```