# Why is \leavevmode required in this example?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, amsthm

In the following mwe, If I comment out `\leavevmode` in the redefinition of the `equation*` environment, the proof title disappears

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59955/172923
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_eqn_width_dim

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldequation* }{ equation* }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldequation* }{ endequation* }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ equation* }{ +b }
  {
    %\leavevmode
    \settowidthofalign{ \l_eqn_width_dim } { #1 }
    \begin{oldequation*} #1 \end{oldequation*}
  }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{equation*}
    a + b = c
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

without `\leavevmode`:

[image]

with `\leavevmode`:

[image]

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: You can instead add the `\leavevmode` to the beginning of the `\settowidthofalign` macro definition.  I would recommend this since the issue arises from the `\setbox\z@=\vbox...` part of the definition.

Comment: I  meant to ask this on your last question, perhaps it is just the small example but what is the intention of the align measurement? You set it all and set the width to a length register but then discard it unused?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The code I posted is just the mwe, in my real use case I do use `\l_eqn_width_dim`.

Comment: @noibe yes I guessed so although it makes answering a bit delicate as the simplest way to solve the problem as written is simply to remove the  `\settowidthofalign` Incidentally why do you measure an align (which is tricky as in principle you have to step over all the alignment cells) when here you know it is a single equation with no alignment `&` so you could simply measure it directly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my code I'm redefining `equation`, `equation*`, `align` and `align*`, and I'm using the same macro, `\settowidthofalign`, to calculate their width. Should I use two different macros, one for `equation`(`*`) and one for `align`(`*`)? How would a hypothetical `\settowidthofequation` work?

Comment: `\settowidth\mylength{$\displaystyle x+y$}`  would be all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `\begin{proof}`, the label “Proof” is obtained with `\item[...]` and it's a standard feature of `trivlist` (that's used for implementing `proof`) that the typesetting of the label is delayed when the first text following it is scanned and typeset.

In your case this happens when `\begin{align*}` ***inside*** the `\vbox` is executed, so the label is lost together with the box.

You need `\leavevmode` at the beginning of `\settowidthofalign`. Just for safety: starting a proof with a display is not the best thing to do anyway.