# automatically adjust the width of align environment

Tags: align, width

I want to make an environment, say `myalign`, that is similar to `align` environment, but satisfying the following additional requirements:

1. `myalign` enables `tag`, and `myalign*` disables it
2. If the width of equations is longer than `\textwidth`, it automatically adjusts its width to `\textwidth`
3. Otherwise, it preserves the width
4. There is an optional argument that allows to change the width to, say `1.1\textwidth`, with the default value of 1

For example, think about the following `align` environment:

```
\begin{align}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\notag\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{align}
```

I can satisfy `2.` using the following code

```
\[\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
$\begin{aligned}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\notag\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{aligned}$}\]
```

but it does not satisfy `1.` and `3.` (plus I don't know how to define it as a new environment)

Moreover, for `4.`, when I change `1\textwidth` to `1.1\textwidth`, then it gives the result which is not centered. I also want to fix this behavior.

[image]

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\verb|\begin{align}...|
\begin{align}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\notag\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{align}

\verb|\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{...|
\[\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
$\begin{aligned}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\notag\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{aligned}$}\]

\verb|\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{...|
\[\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{
$\begin{aligned}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\notag\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{aligned}$}\]

\end{document}
```

---

Based on Mico's suggestion, I have come up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox, calc}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59925
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}

\newcommand{\settowidthofalignstar}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x}

\makeatother

\newlength{\mylen}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{O{1} b}{
    \settowidthofalign{\mylen}{#2}%
    \[\begin{adjustbox}{max width=#1\textwidth, center}%
    \parbox{\maxof{\mylen}{#1\textwidth}}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{align}
    #2
    \end{align}}\end{adjustbox}\notag\]}{}
    
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign*}{O{1} b}{
    \settowidthofalignstar{\mylen}{#2}%
    \[\begin{adjustbox}{max width=#1\textwidth, center}%
    \parbox{\maxof{\mylen}{#1\textwidth}}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \end{align*}}\end{adjustbox}\notag\]}{}

    
\begin{document}


\begin{align}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{align}

\begin{myalign}
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{myalign}

\begin{myalign*}[1.1]
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x+ x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\\
x +y &= x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x \notag
\end{myalign*}

\end{document}
```

This seems to work well, but I'm not sure this is an efficient way to implement this...

Comment: Are you familiar with the [adjustbox](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) package?

Comment: @Mico Can you take a look at the solution I came up with?

Comment: I've noticed that the first two equations in the `myalign` environment are numbered 5 and 6, rather than 3 and 4.  This would appear to be due to the fact that the `amsmath` package performs a preliminary width-measuring step before the typesetting step. Now, there are some ways to fix that. Start by, say, searching this site. Or, you could just post a new query. :-) I feel compelled, though, to try to discourage you from using the `adjustbox` and `resizebox` machinery. Your approach is bound to produce dreadful typographical eye sores which your readers will find distracting and off-putting.